# Meshify a Graphic in order to form and deform it

Tags: modeling

Is there a way to 'meshify' a bitmapped graphic so I can push and pull it in order (in this case) to simulate the crinkles in a the almond bag? I suppose kind of like uv-unwrapping onto a graphic but I want something more direct. Something like select graphic + add polygons and then manipulate the graphic directly.[image]

Comment: That's not how this works... You would need, roughly, to model the bag, possibly sculpt the ripples and then add the materials.

Comment: as @someonewithpc said from an image to a mesh could be impossible ( just model it it looks simple ) then try to extract a bump map from the image and apply it to the model

Comment: Thank you, I was just looking for a short cut (lazy way :).

Comment: @Marc you can post the solution you used/found as an answer

Comment: The closest 'short cut' would be using image as plane, have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

Well the answer is yes you can do it with images but not with blender alone,
and not with a single image as well. What you need to to learn about the modeling
technique using photography.

Currently there are 2 free opensource software VisualSFM and Meshlab that allows
modeller to create 3d models from a set of images there is are tutorial videos
on the youtube that shows you how to use them.

Here is one of the video. The guy even uploaded a set of the images he took
so you could follow those steps. Installing VisualSFM can be abit tricky though.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6eqW6yk50k

Good luck cheers.